# Can I use different package inductor in impedance matching circuit of NRF52832 design

Tags: inductor, impedance-matching, packages

I am designing a custom PCB with NRF52832 IC. According to datsheet, required specification of inductor L1 are:3.9nH, 0402 package, 5% and a High-frequecy chip inductor. Can I use other package inductor(other than 0402) with same specifications?

L1 is a part of impedance matching circuit. Can changing its package impact the circuit perforamce?

Circuit diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That inductor is part of the antenna matching network. Nordic chose 0402 for its lower parasitic capacitance. Pay attention that you have a 0.8pF capacitor near it. If you use an 0805 part, the pads parasitic capacitance will be higher than that.